# Cannot upload files via WinExplorer - There are already a folder

Tags: windows

The problem is that a partner is trying to upload a file, a file not a folder, to her business Sharepoint via the Windows Explorer and she is getting the following error *(translated, the original error is in Spanish)*:

```
There is already a folder with the same name that the specified file. 

Hay ya una carpeta con el mismo nombre que el archivo especificado.
```

The following screenshot, *the resolution is the worst possible but it can be read*.

[image: Screenshot]

But the same file can be uploaded with the Sharepoint *web app* to the same folder that she tried before. Then she refreshed the Windows Explorer windows and the file is there and she can read/write/delete.

Are there some way to solve? Or I should escalate the problem to the Microsoft Support.

### EDIT

I tried with the same file in another computer with the Windows Explorer and it uploaded without errors.
Both machines are Windows 7 64 bits inside the same domain

In the machine, where the error occurs, I created 4 files with random names and the errors still happening.

**Note:** This Windows Explorer is open by the Sharepoint *web app*.

**PS:** Moved from superuser. Thanks to [**@DavidPostill**](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this problem is not occurred in document library. If your folder name is matched with "document name + extension", that time you will get message. Please try with other SharePoint document library.

Comment: I tried with other folders, changing the name of the files but always get de same error. In one try, I changed the name of the file to blue.dabadi but same error. Seems that nothing change. I updated the Q with more information

Comment: Is there OS same in both machine? Which OS have you configured?

Comment: Yes, both machines have Windows 7 64bits

Comment: Restart WebClient service from Local Services. Check by which user you are login and check it again

Comment: I don't guess it will be this, because the machine were rebooted several time but I will try it ;) I should be the monday, now Im out the office. Monday I will try it and tell the results then. Thank you

Comment: I did it several time but didn't work. Sorry for the delay